# Greedy approximate algorithm for metric TSP in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, traveling-salesman

I have [a repository](https://github.com/coderodde/GA4TSP) that provides three metric TSP solvers:

1. Brute-force solver,
2. Genetic solver,
3. Greedy approximate solver;

solver 3 is the subject matter of this post.

The typical output is:

```
GA duration         : 1318 ms.
Brute-force duration: 4212 ms.
Greedy duration:      1 ms.
---
GA cost         : 1430.365851513996
Approximate cost: 1359.474067059351
Brute-force cost: 1216.4965904321161
Cost ratio GA/BF: 1.1758075302175
Cost ratio Approx./BF: 1.1175321638809093
```

And the tours look like this:

[image: yeah1]
[image: yeah2]
[image: yeah3]

```
package com.github.coderodde.tsp.impl;

import com.github.coderodde.tsp.AllPairsShortestPathData;
import com.github.coderodde.tsp.Node;
import com.github.coderodde.tsp.TSPSolver;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class implements a greedy approximate algorithm for solving TSP. First,
 * it selects a shortest edge in the graph and adds it to the tentative tour. 
 * Then, it repeatedly selects the closest node to some of the tour's end 
 * points, and continues so until the tour becomes complete.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Mar 8, 2023)
 * @see 1.6 (Mar 8, 2023)
 */
public final class ApproximateTSPSolver implements TSPSolver {

    private static final class Pair<F, S> {
        F first;
        S second;
        
        Pair(F first, S second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }
    }
    
    private static final int MINIMUM_GRAPH_SIZE = 3;
    
    @Override
    public Solution findTSPSolution(Node seedNode) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(seedNode, "The seed node is null.");
        
        List<Node> reachableNodes = 
                GraphExpander.computeReachableNodesFrom(seedNode);
        
        checkGraphSize(reachableNodes.size());
        
        AllPairsShortestPathData allPairsData = 
                AllPairsShortestPathSolver.solve(reachableNodes);
        
        Deque<Node> tentativeTour = new ArrayDeque<>();
        
        Pair<Node, Node> initialEdge = getInitialEdge(reachableNodes,
                                                      allPairsData);
        
        tentativeTour.addLast(initialEdge.first);
        tentativeTour.addLast(initialEdge.second);
        
        Set<Node> visitedSet = new HashSet<>();
        
        visitedSet.add(initialEdge.first);
        visitedSet.add(initialEdge.second);
        
        while (tentativeTour.size() < reachableNodes.size()) {
            Node head = tentativeTour.getFirst();
            Node tail = tentativeTour.getLast();
            
            Node nearestToHead = getNearestNeighborOf(head, 
                                                      visitedSet,
                                                      reachableNodes,
                                                      allPairsData);
            
            Node nearestToTail = getNearestNeighborOf(tail, 
                                                      visitedSet, 
                                                      reachableNodes,
                                                      allPairsData);
            
            if (allPairsData.getShortestPathCost(head, nearestToHead) <
                allPairsData.getShortestPathCost(tail, nearestToTail)) {
                tentativeTour.addFirst(nearestToHead);
                visitedSet.add(nearestToHead);
            } else {
                tentativeTour.addLast(nearestToTail);
                visitedSet.add(nearestToTail);
            }
        } 
        
        return new Solution(
                tentativeTourToResultTour(tentativeTour), 
                allPairsData);
    }
    
    private static Node 
        getNearestNeighborOf(
                Node node, 
                Set<Node> visitedSet,
                List<Node> graphNodes,
                AllPairsShortestPathData allPairsData) {
        
        double tentativeCost = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        Node nearestNeighbor = null;
        
        for (Node neighbor : graphNodes) {
            if (visitedSet.contains(neighbor)) {
                continue;
            }
            
            double cost = 
                    allPairsData.getShortestPathCost(
                            node,
                            neighbor);

            if (tentativeCost > cost) {
                tentativeCost = cost;
                nearestNeighbor = neighbor;
            }
        }
        
        return nearestNeighbor;
    }
    
    private static Pair<Node, Node> 
        getInitialEdge(List<Node> reachableNodes,
                       AllPairsShortestPathData allPairsData) {
        double tentativeCost = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        Node tentativeNode1 = null;
        Node tentativeNode2 = null;
        
        for (Node node : reachableNodes) {
            for (Node neighbor : node.getNeighbors()) {
                if (neighbor.equals(node)) {
                    continue;
                }
                
                double cost = 
                        allPairsData.getShortestPathCost(
                                node,
                                neighbor);
                
                if (tentativeCost > cost) {
                    tentativeCost = cost;
                    tentativeNode1 = node;
                    tentativeNode2 = neighbor;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return new Pair<>(tentativeNode1, tentativeNode2);
    }
    
    private static List<Node> tentativeTourToResultTour(Deque<Node> nodeDeque) {
        return new ArrayList<>(nodeDeque);
    }
    
    private static void checkGraphSize(int numberOfNodes) {
        if (numberOfNodes < MINIMUM_GRAPH_SIZE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Too little graph nodes: " 
                            + numberOfNodes 
                            + ". Must be at least " 
                            + MINIMUM_GRAPH_SIZE
                            + ".");
        }
    }
}
```

**Critique request**

So how am I doing here? Any ideas are much welcomed.

Comment: If you post your brute-force one too we talk about the algorithm, you can do better than O(n! * n) (in various ways)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private static final int MINIMUM_GRAPH_SIZE = 3;
```

Maybe this, and some checking code,
should be evicted to a common class used by all three TSP variants?
Also the check could produce a more diagnostic message,
for the case where caller offers three nodes with zero edges.

```
    private static final class Pair<F, S> {
```

Same argument.
Or if you're willing to depend on e.g. javafx or apache commons,
there's lots of definitions for this trivial struct.

This declaration is clear

```
Pair<Node, Node> initialEdge
```

but I'm sad that it isn't `Edge initialEdge`.

I am accustomed to TSP being formulated on an undirected graph.
I eventually noticed that this code tackles the harder problem
of finding a tour on a digraph.
Some input digraphs will happen to have symmetric edges,
which this class will eventually discover.
I wonder if that costs us cycles?
Also, `checkGraphSize` will accept the graph A -> B -> C,
neglecting to report that it lacks a C -> A edge.

I feel stricter error checking is warranted.
If caller passes in N nodes, we should find exactly N nodes reachable.
And we shouldn't permit any node to have out-degree of zero.

---

Wow, `AllPairsShortestPathSolver.solve()` looks expensive.
And I don't mean the extra factor of 2 due to directed edges.

There's a bunch of hashmap lookups, and each of them is "fast",
I suppose, happening in O(1) time.
But they're not cache friendly,
something that is especially relevant for `solve()`,
given the quadratic size.

In python land everything tends to involve chasing an object pointer, also,
which explains the popularity of the numpy library.
You *can* put a bunch of float objects in a container,
but they will be more rapidly scanned if we put them
in a contiguously allocated vector of floats.
Why? Because we're not stalled on a random read
for pointer dereference, and because the hardware
notices sequential scans and has already populated
the cache line with the adjacent floats you're
going to need a moment from now.

If you *do* choose to implement `solve()`
with an `array`, use the smallest bits-per-entry
you can get away with, so a cache line will
accommodate more entries.

---

I wish `getInitialEdge` explained that it finds
the minimum edge weight and returns one of those edges.
Its [contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
seems to suggest it's free to choose any arbitrary edge.
So the quadratic cost surprised me.

---

`getNearestNeighborOf` is a nice name, but maybe rename it to
`getNearestUnvisitedNeighborOf` ?
Or explain that in a comment.

Could we maybe reduce its cost from O(N) to O(log N)
by sorting the all-pairs data?